# Odoo 10, Importing res partner with tags with an XML when installing a module

Tags: import, odoo

I need to import customers data with tags into *res.partner* with an XML when installing a custom module.

"*Customers*" data is stored in *res.partner* and "*Tags*" data is stored in *res.partner.category*, they have a relationship Many2many through *res_partner_res_partner_category_rel*.

I'm calling two XML files in the *__manifest__.py*:

**The first one populates successfully res.partner.category:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="res.partner.category" id="res_partner_category_1">
        <field name="name">Heavy metal</field>
        <field name="active">1</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

**The second one inserts the partner data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <odoo>
    <record model="res.partner" id="res_partner_predata_1">
        <field name="name">Iron Maiden</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

All I need is to insert this *res.partner* registry with the "*Heavy metal*" **Tag** with the installation of a custom module like this:

This is how it would look:

[image: This is how it would look]

I will deeply appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the Odoo demo data:
When I created the category **Heavy metal** I assigned the id **res_partner_predata_1**, then I only have to add the next line (*the one after the comment*) to the **res_partner** registry like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <odoo>
    <record model="res.partner" id="res_partner_predata_1">
        <field name="name">Iron Maiden</field>
        <--! This line will add the category-->
        <field eval="[(6, 0, [ref('module_name.res_partner_category_1')])]" name="category_id"/>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question with odoo 14. In my case your solution did not work completely. Instead of:

```
   <field eval="[(6, 0, [ref('module_name.res_partner_category_1')])]" name="category_id"/>
```

I had to set:

```
   <field name="category_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('res_partner_category_1')])]"/>
```